# Django | ManyToMany permite añadir en modo administrador pero no en frontend

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

En modo administrador al añadir nueva actuación, una de las columnas (llamada Fallo) la tengo de tipo ManyToMany. Todo perfecto al crear en modo administrador: se puede seleccionar varios pulsando Control, y si quiero añadir otro elemento, puedo clicar en el "+" para añadir otro.

**Así se visualiza en el administrador:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En cambio en el frontend sí que permite selección multiple mediante control, pero no permite añadir más elementos, no hay ese "+" (ejemplo si quisiera añadir: Fallo Batería, Fallo Tarjeta, etc.).

**Así se visualiza en el frontend:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo se puede visualizar ese "+" o ese poder añadir más elementos en el frontend?

**Archivo Models.py**

```
class Actuacion(models.Model):
    fallo = models.ManyToManyField(TipoFallo)
```

**Archivo Views.py**

```
class ActuacionAdd(CreateView):
    template_name = 'actuacion/add.html'
    model = Actuacion
    form_class = CrearActuacionForm
    success_url = '/actuacion/'
```

**Archivo forms.py**

```
class CrearActuacionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Actuacion
        fields = ('__all__')
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CrearActuacionForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['fallo'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control'})
```

Gracias.

Comment: Ese "+", es del admin de Django, no es que Django genere ese "+" o que los forms o widgets puedan generar ese "+", tienes que hacerlo tu y de hecho ese "+" es en realidad un enlace que redirige a la creación del objeto, en tu caso un "Fallo".

Comment: Ok entiendo, consiste en hacer un enlace a una clase add (CreateView) para crear más elementos. ¿Es así?

Comment: Exacto, eso es.